# How to integrate tableau server's credential with asp.net mvc web-server's credential ?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, tableau-api, credential-manager

We can embed or place the tableau report easily inside web-page using the tableau provided script. But, tableau server has it's own credential. That's why report in the web-page provides a login popup window inside the page, which is not expected.

I want to be logged in to the tableau server with the login credential of the website and just see the web-page and the report without any tableau server credential. Tableau server will provide the report by taking the webpage credential so that user don't feel that he needs several credentials to view the web-page along with tableau report.

please, suggest me...what should I do now ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your data sources are extracts (or that credentials have been embedded for live connections), then your best best is to use [trusted tickets](http://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/server/en-us/help.htm#trusted_auth.htm)

Comment: If this information answers your question, then please remember to mark it as the accepted answer. :)